# Firefox title tab is not dark altough dark theme is ON, Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, gtk

As title says, I always set the "Dark theme" on because light colors damage my sight. Since I've formatted my laptop and set the dark theme on the firefox title tab doesn't seem to set to dark as the rest of tabs from other applications.

Any way to make this possible?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the active window's title bar will be darker/lighter than other window title bars to indicate that it is the active window.  Would it be possible for you to provide a screen shot of your issue, including Firefox, as well as another application's title bar that you feel is working properly?

Comment: i've added a screenshot @earthmeLon

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there isn't another window with which we can compare the intended (correct) visual vs what it is you're seeing currently.  While Firefox will use many of your Gnome Theme settings, maybe you're missing a Firefox theme itself that you had installed previously, such as [FT DeepDark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ft-deepdark/)?  I wonder if Unity could be causing issues...

Comment: its GNOME, not Unity, it also was Unity before

Comment: The title area is just a small area of the screen. If you have a problem with light colors, you would want to fix the entire screen!

Comment: well it's still annoying to me ;/

Comment: I posted a fix here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/976772/firefox-dark-theme-has-a-white-bar-on-top-17-10/978540#978540