# Firefox dark theme has a white bar on top (17.10)

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, 17.10

With the release of firefox 58 I decided I would give it a go after having used chrome for a very long time, and so far the transition has been seamless, however I came across a rather annoying problem, I use a dark theme, but for some reason the top bar of Firefox is white. I have enabled the dark theme in the firefox settings.

- Ubuntu 17.10
- firefox from ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next (as per [here](https://itsfoss.com/firefox-quantum-ubuntu/))
- arc-dark theme

[image: Example]

Is it possible to make that bar dark too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox has no control over the white bar you mentioned, it is dictated by your "Applications" (GTK+) theme.

To change the theme open *(GNOME) Tweaks* and go to "Appearance" section. Select a different theme (which has a dark title bar) for "*Applications*" under *Themes*.

You can get more themes from sources like [GNOME-LOOK.ORG](https://www.opendesktop.org/s/Gnome).

Comment: So it was actually up to the arc-theme that needs an update, interesting..
I settled for Adapta, thank you for your help!

Comment: I see the same bar but my theme and all other windows use Minwaita and the top bar for all other windows is therefore dark.

This fix doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Nicolay77 In that case I would suggest you to ask a new question as it's pretty hard for this question to get any more attention. If you do so, don't forget to link this question and *explicitly mention* that the accepted answer here doesn't work for you. Also provide details like GTK+ theme, screenshots where it's working and where it doesn't etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `about:config`.

Search for `widget.chrome.allow-gtk-dark-theme`.

Change it to `true`.

Restart Firefox.